# What is the best way to display a lot of text in Flex mobile application?

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, text

What is the best way to display a large amount of text (5000-10000 words) in a Flex mobile app?

I have been loading text in through an xml file using itemrenderer.  It works totally fine when I run the application on my PC but when I load it onto my Android phone it crashes.  Looks like my phone can only handle loading in about 3000 words using this method without crashing.

Anyone have a suggestion?  Also, HTML isn't going to work for me.  I want the text built into the application, which is why I have been trying to use the xml file.

Thanks!

Comment: We can't answer this question of "Best way to display large amounts of text" without knowing the reason you want to display large amounts of text.  Are you displaying individual words in a dataGroup so they can be interacted with?  Or something else?

Comment: I am interested in displaying just plain readable text.

Comment: Just messing around with it and <s:Label> </s:Label> in a Group will store 10000+ words. It loads fairly slow on my android phone but at least it doesn't crash. If someone can think of a cleaner way to do this, that would great. Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to display text; use a TextArea.  No need to muck around with itemRenderers or DataGroups.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html

Comment: This is a big improvement.  It loads fairly quick and is easier to work with.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it up as a formal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just display a lot of text, I recommend using a [TextArea](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html).

There is no need to deal with DataGroups and itemRenderers unless you have a specific need for a list based approach.